# Does "yar" (or "yarr" or "yargh") in Pirate English imply an affirmative?

Tags: meaning, exclamations, pirate-english

In honor of International Talk Like A Pirate Day, I’d like to ask a question about the pirate dialect of English.  Most pirate sentences begin with a standard pirate-sounding hedge to lend authenticity.

A frequent hedge is *arr*, but the variations *yar*, *yarr*, and *yargh* are also quite common. Is there a distinction in meaning between *arr* and the *yar* variants, or are these simply different spellings of the same exclamation? For instance, is *yar* a contraction of *yes* and *arr*, therefore implying an affirmation or agreement?

Comment: Off-topic: You should post this at pirate-talk.stackexchange.com

Comment: Avast, me matey, EL&U be pirate.SE on this fine September day!

Comment: If that be, then blow me down! Arrrgh!

Comment: +1 I love pirates, even if I don't talk like them.

Comment: Belay that, JeffSahol, ye must be addled to be a-thinking of such bilge!

Comment: "Yargh" sounds more like an indicator that the speaker has just been forced to walk the plank.

Comment: I be seeing many answers, but none that has a sourcin'...

Comment: Ye scurvey landlubber, *yar* be askin' what *yarr* be standin' for? *Yargh*, ye be nuttin' bu' a scurvy bilgerat-- nay, ye be an ARISTOCRAT! It be the plank at dawn fer ye! (An' yarr, yarr be meanin' yes. Th'others be meanin' other things.)

Comment: If none can answer well, they can all walk the plank, you cyber lubbers!

Comment: Din't yer never use the werd?

Comment: @JeffSahol Area 51, anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JeffSahol be right, tis usually a placeholder but nay, it be not as 'like' in ValSpeak for tis always an exclamation.  Ye hear many a pirate say "Arrr!" meanin' aye, but Long John Silver ere, ee meant it oft times as *nay!*, as ye may see with yer own pirate eyes and ears in [this ere](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yC_PR7YWQOc#t=6m) video clip.

Answer (score 5):

It be like "ano" in Japanese, me boy, or "like" in valspeak, a verbal placeholder.

Answer (score 5):

"Yarr: v. i.    1.  To growl or snarl as a dog." — [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary, published 1913 by C. & G. Merriam Co.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Yarr)
The top definition on [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=yarr!) agrees.

I think the positive meaning relates to "yare" (Adjective 1. Ready; dexterous; eager; lively; quick to move. Adverb 1. Soon. — [Websters](http://www.websters-online-dictionary.org/definitions/yare)). As does [this page](http://www.ehow.com/about_6648519_meaning-yar_.html):

> According to the Dictionary of English Nautical Language Database,
>   "yare," also pronounced "yahr" and derived from the Old High German
>   word, "garo," meaning "ready," refers to a well-designed,
>   easy-to-handle boat. "Yar" is also connected to the Gaelic word,
>   "garbh," meaning "rugged," which accounts for the naming of the River
>   Yar on the Isle of Wight.

Comment: *Very* interesting. I've never heard of that word before. Thanks!

Comment: Yare - Surely it's "Adjective 1. Ready; &c"? @KitFox, you'll find 'yarely' used in *Tmp* I,i.

Comment: @StoneyB, good catch. I've sent [Cassidy](http://www.websters-online-dictionary.org/credits/websters.html#) an email about that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be contendin' that 'Yarrrgh!!' would be an affirmation' of yer yabberin'; whereas 'Aaarrghh!' would be refutin' yer spurious claims.

Yaarrrgghh!!

Comment: Uh, this is very interesting. Hopefully any other contributions you choose to make here will not be so piratey.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is a battle cry, used in pirate times. It had developed from German. It also is defo right so avast ye, ye scurvy barnacles